# Does the sum of all entries ("grand sum") of a density matrix have any meaning or a particular value?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, linear-algebra, density-operator

Title says it all really. As is commonly known, the trace of the density matrix must be one and the trace over the density matrix times an operator is the expectation value of that operator. If you instead add up ALL the entries of the matrix (perhaps times some function related to the row/column indices) does this represent something OR does it equal some numerical value? Does it have some numerical relationship to the trace (strictly greater, or smaller, etc.?)

Comment: The matrix representing a density operator is basis dependent.

Comment: Good point @TobiasFünke I was hoping (like for the trace) there might be some property independent of the basis - but failing that I'm current using Fock (but could switch to another like coherent or quadrature if there is some property in those representations)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The sum of all elements is a real number, as $\rho = \rho^\dagger$ so
   $$\sum_{ij} \rho_{ij} = \sum_{i<j} (
   \rho_{ij} + \underbrace{\rho_{ji}}_{\rho_{ij}^*} ) + \sum_i \rho_{ii} = 2 \sum_{i<j} \Re e( \rho_{ij}) + \mathrm{tr}(\rho) $$
2. It is basis dependent. It corresponds to the expectation value $\mathrm{tr}(\rho O)$ of an operator $O$ whose matrix elements are all 1 in the chosen basis:
   $$ \mathrm{tr}(\rho O) = \sum_{i,j} \rho_{ij} \underbrace{O_{ji}}_{=\,1} $$
   It is easy to see this is basis dependent, as $O = O^\dagger$, so there is a basis where $O$ is diagonal. In consequence, $O$ can not be all ones in all bases.

   I think, usually the operator $O$ will not have a useful interpretation. For concrete systems and bases it may occasionally have an interpreation. E.g. for a spin $\frac 1 2$ system, it will be $1 + \sigma_x$ (when evaluating the sum in $\sigma_z$ basis).

Comment: I think the wording is a bit misleading:$\mathrm{Tr}\,\rho O$ is basis independent, for any operator $O$. You are right that the sum of the elements of a density matrix in a given (orthonormal) basis can be written as the expectation value of an operator $O$ which has as matrix elements $O_{ij}=1$ in that said basis. But evaluating the trace in the eigenbasis of $O$ still evaluates to the sum of the matrix elements of the density matrix in the original basis.The sum of the matrix elements is basis dependent simply because the matrix elements are, i.e. this can be seen from your first equation.

Comment: Well I though I wrote this clearly enough, I'll edit later to make this clearer.

Comment: (By the way, I don't find it immediately obvious from the first equation, that the quantity is basis dependent. E.g. the determinant is also a combination of all the basis dependent matrix elements, nevertheless it is invariant under basis change.)

Comment: Well, the first equation is basically sum of all ements= trace (basis independent)  + sum of off-diagonal elements (which are clearly basis dependent, since e.g. a density matrix can be diagonalized). Put differently, the sum of all matrix elements is basis-independent if and only if the sum of the real parts of all off-diagonal elements are. This is what your first equation shows.

Answer (score 0):

In classical mechanics the partition sum Z(T,V) is the integral of the density over all of phase space. It represents the total weight of a unnormalized probability distribution.

By the quotients of derivatives with respect to the parameters one gets expectation values of the observable quantities tied as coefficients to the parameters.

For exponential densities

$$ \rho(T)=e^{-\frac{p^2 +\Phi(x)}{2 m k T}}\quad d^nx(V) \wedge d^np $$

logarithmic derivative wrt to $1/T$ yields the expectation of the total Energy. So, for simplicity, the function  $ k T \log Z$ gets the name "free energy".

For non-equilibrium states there are no general rules, how to reproduce the relevant observable quantities from the  partition function.

The quantum partition function assumes a spectrum of the total Hamiltonian somehow proportional to $p^2 = \hbar k^2 $ in a free particle representation of the N-particle symmetrized Hilbert space for $N$ identical particles in a box with unnormalized probabilities $p_n = d(n) e^{- \frac{E_n}{k T}}$ with discrete spectrum $E_n$ and finitely summable occupation number d(n).

Thus by the principles, $p =  e^{- \frac{E_n}{k T}}$ is a positive operator with finite trace. The trace is invariant with respect to basis transforms of the N-particle Hilbert space.

The quantum expectation values of operators in a diagonal basis of the Hamiltonian multiplied by the Boltzmann exponential for $E_n$ and the degeneration factor, summed of all states and normalized by the trace of the density operator defines a probability model for temperature states. As in classical mechanics, $k T \log Z$ is the free energy.

All matrix elements of the density are basis dependent, only the trace of products of operators with the density are independent of the basis.